# I want fill an empty SharePoint-Online List using .csv file with help of JavaScript

Tags: sharepoint-online

What I want to achieve is that I have a SharePoint-Online list by the name DemoList which has 5 columns.
Instead of filling the fields by clicking 'Quick Edit' I have an Excel Sheet which has the data that needs to be filled in the SP-Online List.
Now I want to import the data from Excel sheet to SPList such that even in future if I have updated the values of existing data in the Excel or Or new data is added to the list I should be to update the existing sp list instead of creating a new ist

Comment: Why don’t you just import the Excel file as a list?

Comment: Okay thanks, but what if I want to update the list and the Excel Sheet has both the old data which may or may not be updated and plus new rows of data

Comment: Without more info I can only say this:

Comment: then only request the Delta of the data

Comment: I am sorry I am new to SharePoint, could you please elaborate above point. Is there a way to update existing file without creating new?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say if this is your one time requirement, just import the excel into the empty list.

And if this is your recurring requirement, create a PowerShell script to read the csv and read item one by one then insert each row in the SharePoint list.

To make this to happen automatically, configure this PS script in Windows task scheduler.

Below is the sample PowerShell script how to read CSV and create item in SharePoint online list :

```
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"
Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files\Common Files\microsoft shared\Web Server Extensions\15\ISAPI\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"
#next pass the credentials and connect to web
$siteURL = "https://hubto.sharepoint.com/sites/learnhub"
$Listname="sitecollections"
$userName = "User.onmicrosoft.com"
$PlainPassword = "Password"
$ImportFile ="D: \Powershell\LearnPowershell\Test.csv"
$password = $PlainPassword | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force

# set SharePoint Online credentials
$SPOCredentials = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.SharePointOnlineCredentials($userName, $password)

#Creating client context object
$clientContext = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext($siteURL) 
$clientContext.credentials = $SPOCredentials $web = $clientContext.Web 
$clientContext.load($web)

#Get the List
$List = $clientContext.Web.Lists.GetByTitle($Listname)
$clientContext.Load($List) 
$clientContext.executeQuery()

$csv = Import-CSV $ImportFile foreach($row in $csv) { 
    #Creat single list Items
    $ListItenCreationInformation =New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ListItemCreationInformation
    $NewListItem = $List.AddItem($ListItenCreationInformation)
    $NewListItem["Sourcesite"] = $row.Sourcesite
    $NewListItem["TargetSite"] = $row.TargetSite
    $NewListItem["WaveId"] = $row.WaveId
    $NewListItem["Status"] = $row.Status
    $NewListItem.Update()
    $ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
}
Write-Host "Items Added to List Sucessfully"
```

**Reference URL:**

[Steps to add items from CSV file to SharePoint Online List using PowerShell in CSOM](https://www.enjoysharepoint.com/steps-to-add-items-from-csv-file-to-sharepoint-online-list-using-powershell-in-csom/)

As an alternate, using the below Power Automate (Microsoft Flow) also can do same thing:

[Read CSV file and create/update list items with logic](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Read-CSV-file-and-create-update-list-items-with-logic/td-p/103725)

Comment: I did try MS Flow option and it did work to an end. I am facing few issues to change the logic based on my fields. Currently, I am able to add data to my list but for the already existing data, it creates a duplicate. For Eg: If I have an excel sheet with 10 records and after 1st execution, the data is added to the list. If the sheet is updated and new 4 records are added and already existing data is modified. So now if I run the flow the existing data in the list remains as is and new more 14 fields are added. So now the list has 24 records.

Answer (score 0):

Without more info I can only say this:

1. Ask your data provider to send the data as JSON.
   Otherwise:
2. Your data should reside in an actual database and be imported from such a database.
3. Since your question is tagged as
   ‘SharePoint-online’ I would recommend that you take a close look at  ***PowerApps***.

Look, you are getting this data from either an internal or an external source.
If it’s internal, you need to talk to your data provider about better, more sophisticated options.  If your export is coming from an external vendor or department, you may be stuck with it.

Comment: I have updated my question and I have tried to be specific. I hope you'll be able to help

Answer (score 0):

You could use the script [Reading CSV file with Javascript and HTML5 File API](https://github.com/MounirMesselmeni/html-fileapi)

processDataAsObj will check the first row as header.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function handleFiles(files) {
            // Check for the various File API support.
            if (window.FileReader) {
                // FileReader are supported.
                getAsText(files[0]);
            } else {
                alert('FileReader are not supported in this browser.');
            }
        }

        function getAsText(fileToRead) {
            var reader = new FileReader();
            // Handle errors load
            reader.onload = loadHandler;
            reader.onerror = errorHandler;
            // Read file into memory as UTF-8
            reader.readAsText(fileToRead);
        }

        function loadHandler(event) {
            var csv = event.target.result;
            //processData(csv);
            processDataAsObj(csv);
        }

        function processData(csv) {
            var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            var lines = [];
            while (allTextLines.length) {
                lines.push(allTextLines.shift().split(','));
            }
            console.log(lines);
            drawOutput(lines);
        }

        //if your csv file contains the column names as the first line
        function processDataAsObj(csv) {
            var allTextLines = csv.split(/\r\n|\n/);
            var lines = [];

            //first line of csv
            var keys = allTextLines.shift().split(',');

            while (allTextLines.length) {
                var arr = allTextLines.shift().split(',');
                var obj = {};
                for (var i = 0; i < keys.length; i++) {
                    obj[keys[i]] = arr[i];
                }
                lines.push(obj);
            }
            console.log(lines);
            drawOutputAsObj(lines);
        }

        function errorHandler(evt) {
            if (evt.target.error.name == "NotReadableError") {
                alert("Canno't read file !");
            }
        }

        function drawOutput(lines) {
            //Clear previous data
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
            var table = document.createElement("table");
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                for (var j = 0; j < lines[i].length; j++) {
                    var firstNameCell = row.insertCell(-1);
                    firstNameCell.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i][j]));
                }
            }
            document.getElementById("output").appendChild(table);
        }

        //draw the table, if first line contains heading
        function drawOutputAsObj(lines) {
            //Clear previous data
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = "";
            var table = document.createElement("table");

            //for the table headings
            var tableHeader = table.insertRow(-1);
            Object.keys(lines[0]).forEach(function (key) {
                var el = document.createElement("TH");
                el.innerHTML = key;
                tableHeader.appendChild(el);
            });

            //the data
            for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
                var row = table.insertRow(-1);
                Object.keys(lines[0]).forEach(function (key) {
                    var data = row.insertCell(-1);
                    data.appendChild(document.createTextNode(lines[i][key]));
                });
            }
            document.getElementById("output").appendChild(table);
        }

    </script>
    <label for="csvFileInput">
        <strong>CSV File:</strong>
    </label>
    <input type="file" id="csvFileInput" onchange="handleFiles(this.files)"
           accept=".csv">
    <div id="output">
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: My excel sheet is stored in a folder in 'Site Contents' of my SharePoint-Online Site. So will be able to update my list based on the changes made in the excel sheet in future?

Comment: Also, I executed the file and after displaying all the rows, the last row displays all the fields as 'undefined'